# Related products dropdown menu in product page

Tags: magento

I would like to create a dropdown menu prefilled with related products on the product page.
I came across the code below which displays all products in a dropdown menu. I pasted it in the file view.phtml and proved to be working. How can I modify it to display related products instead?

```
<select>
<?php
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
    foreach ($products as $prod_model) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_model->getId());
        echo "<option value=\"".$product->getId()."\">".$product->getName()."</option>";
    }
?>
```

I also found out that I could do it through SKU's and came across this code that retrieves the ID's of the matching products:

```
$match = substr($product->getSku(), 0, 4);
$resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$select = $read->select()
->from(array('e'=>$resource->getTableName('catalog/product')), 'entity_id')
->where("e.sku LIKE '" . $match . "%'");
$ids = $read->fetchAll($select);
```

I just want to know how to link both codes together, by either using the related products or SKU.
Can anybody help me on that? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$products = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection()->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
```

To have your collection of related products.